# SQL how to remove new lines on string end?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

Encountered issue when I needed to remove (or replace) new lines at the string end:

Somthing like this

```
-----
test


----
```

to

```
----
test
----
```

I encountered some examples such as

```
isnull(LEFT(fielddata, LEN(fielddata) - PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(9)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(12)+CHAR(13)+']%', REVERSE(fielddata))+1),'') as ResultValue
```

But it doesn't seems to work well (in some cases there are still new lines left). It might be more appropriate to use something like regex `^\s+$`, but I'm not sure how it supposed to look (just putting regex into example doesn't seems to work)

Can you help me with this please?

**UPDATE**

`----` Is not a part of string! I simply don't know how else I suppose to show here string before (with new lines) and string after without them.

**UPDATE 2**

Found a reason why previous example didn't work in any situation. It does nothing in case if string contains ONLY new lines (yep, I have those kind of situations)

Comment: Are the `----` lines part of the result set or just delimiting it for demonstration? Are all of the records formatted the same way with extra space at the end? Is it a bunch of extra spaces or the carriage return characters?

Comment: `PATINDEX()` suggests you are using MS SQL Server, not MySQL. I'm retagging this accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The TRANSLATE() function should do the trick (REGEXP_REPLACE() would also work, but is more inefficient):

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(your_col, chr(10)||chr(11)||chr(13), '') FROM YOUR_TAB;
```

This should remove all newlines, CRs and tabstops. If that's not enough (because the blank line in your example consists of many single spaces or something), you might have to adjust.

Comment: The problem is, it will remove all new lines. I need to remove only last ones.

Comment: In that case I suggest using T-SQL (if you are indeed on a SQL-Server DBMS) and solving this programmatically by using appropriate control structures

Answer (score 0):

You can try below, should work as you're expecting.

```
DECLARE @TEST NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'TEST
'
SELECT @TEST --test before 

SET @TEST = (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@TEST, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''))
SELECT @TEST --test after
```